# Are $\frac{\pi}{e}$ or $\frac{e}{\pi}$ irrational?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is it clear whether $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{e}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{e}{\pi}$ are irrational or not?

If not, then there would exist $q,p\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$p\cdot \pi = q\cdot e$$

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33817/work-on-independence-of-pi-and-e - your question is equivalent to "Are $\pi$ and $e$ linearly independent?"

Comment: You probably mean $p,q\in\Bbb N$, since with rational coefficients you would only need one of them. This kind of questions can be extremely hard to answer, and this one appears to be open. But I think it would be fair to say that it would be extremely surprising if such coefficients existed, any nobody is betting on that outcome.

Comment: The irrationality of both $e+\pi$ and  $\frac{e}{\pi}$ is an open problem till today (unnecessary to mention besides $\frac{\pi}{e}$)

Comment: @Piquito You should mention that in your answer.

Comment: Please leave answers as answers, not as comments. This is not how the site works.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Not equivalent, but is a special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A QUITE SIMPLE REMARK  $$\begin{cases}\frac{e}{\pi}=t\\e+\pi=s\end{cases}\qquad (*)$$ would imply $$\pi=\frac{s}{t+1}\\e=\frac{st}{t+1}$$ Consequently and least one of $t$ and $s$ in (*) must be trascendental.

Comment: Surely this only requires that $s$ be irrational.  It cannot rule out $t$ being rational.

Comment: @StephenG: Can you explain it little bit?